# How to store a df.column in a list without index in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy, iteration

```
df.shape (15,4)
```

I want to store 4th column of df within the loop in a list. What I'm trying is:

```
l=[]
n=1000 #No. of iterations
for i in range(0,n):
    #df expressions and results calcualtion equations
    l.append(df.iloc[:,2]) # This is storing values with index. I want to store then without indices while keeping inplace=True.

df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.array(l), columns = df.index)
```

I want **l** list to append only values from df column 3. Not series object of pandas.core.series module in each cell.

Comment: you want that 3rd column of a df stored as a list in another list over 1000 times?

Comment: Yes precisely, but without indices. This loop is taking a lot of time to run if iteration is increased further

Comment: this works - df.iloc[:,2].tolist ?

Comment: No. It's storing values as method objects in the list l.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot the paranthesis.. I mean try `df.iloc[:,2].tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.iloc[:,2]).tolist()` inside append to get the desired result.

Comment: And how to make 3d list into pandas df on same index? I'm able to merge them, but not on index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782474/converting-3d-list-into-pandas-single-dataframe-on-same-index