# Converting 3d list into pandas single dataframe on same index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy, iteration

My list `l` has shape `np.array(l).shape (100,15,1)` It has 100 dataframes with each df having 15 rows and 1 column. The index are same, just the sorting is different in each df of list.
I want to unzip the list l:

```
l[0] =             Rank                  l[31] =           Rank
           A1       1                                A5      1
           A2       2                                A1      2
           A3       3                                A8      3
           A4       4.. till 15                      A3      4 .... also till 15
```

I want a single dataframe from this 3-d list `l` something like  this:
`df=` `(15,100)`

```
     0       1      2
A1   1       2      3
A2   2       3      2 
A3   3       6      1
A4   4       4      4
A5   5       8      6 .. till 100 columns and for all 15 indices
```

Basically, a dataframe with all ranking lists to be shown on same index only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` and `ignore_index=True` for default new columns by `range`:

```
df = pd.concat(l, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
      0    1
A1  1.0  2.0
A2  2.0  NaN
A3  3.0  4.0
A4  4.0  NaN
A5  NaN  1.0
A8  NaN  3.0
```